# Consulta json en c#

Tags: c#, json

Me gustar recorrer un json añidado y aunque lo haya intentado desde varios focos, no lo consigo.
Seguro que al final se puede reslver de un modo mas simple y por ello os agradecería vuestra ayuda.

tengo estas clases:

```
public class Visitor
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int group_id { get; set; }
        public int? returning_visitor_id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string photo_url { get; set; }
        public string badge_url { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public DateTime in_datetime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? out_datetime { get; set; }
        public object expected_datetime { get; set; }
        public AdditionalFields additional_fields { get; set; }
        public PersonalFields personal_fields { get; set; }
        public List<object> qr_codes { get; set; }
        public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root_Visitor
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public List<Visitor> lista { get; set; }
    }
```

...

y el json que consigo tiene este formato:

```
{{
  "id": 21987,
  "name": "Visitors",
  "type": "non-returning",
  "visitors": [
    {
      "id": 46991868,
      "group_id": 21987,
      "returning_visitor_id": null,
      "name": "Pilar",
      "photo_url": "https://zzzz.com/photos/q0tUq61aWT0acnlNoC38sPmzFiP.jpg",
      "badge_url": "https://zzzz.com/badges/DswqAfDwxkKxfrQLs16nG6j3.jpg",
      "status": "signed_out",
      "in_datetime": "2021-05-17T10:59:16Z",
      "out_datetime": "2021-05-17T10:59:45Z",
      "expected_datetime": null,
      "additional_fields": {
        "Empresa / Company": "Bolsas",
        "Motivo / About": "Reunion ",
        "Acceso Zona Restringida Fabricación? / Access to Restricted Area?": "Yes"
      },
      "personal_fields": null,
      "qr_codes": [],
      "metadata": {
        "rejected_sign_in": false
      }
    }
  ]
}}
```

El tema es que consigo los datos de id, name y type, pero no consigo obtener los datos de "visitors".

Por ello, para la primera parte realizo este comando:

```
List<Root_Visitor> ListVisitor = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root_Visitor>>(httpResponseResult);
```

y en esta lista, me gustaría obtener los datos del sub array visitor.

```
foreach (Root_Visitor visit in ListVisitor)
                {
                    
                }
```

El tema es que ListVisitor sí tiene datos, pero no consigo acceder a la Lista.

A ver si me podeis ayudar por favor.
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes porque la clase `Root_Visitor`, no contiene una propiedad llamada `visitors`. En su lugar tienes una propiedad llamada `lista`, pero nada le indica a la librería que `visitors` debe ser deserializado en `lista`.

Para resolverlo tienes dos opciones:

La más obvia es cambiar el nombre a la propiedad `lista` por `visitors`

```
public class Root_Visitor
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }

    //                    | cambia el nombre a la propiedad 'lista'
    //                    V
    public List<Visitor> visitors { get; set; }
}
```

La otra opción, si quieres que la propiedad se siga llamando `lista`, es utilizar el atributo [`JsonProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm) para establecer la equivalencia en el nombre de la propiedad.

```
public class Root_Visitor
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }

    //  | Agrega este atributo
    //  V
    [JsonProperty("visitors")]
    public List<Visitor> lista { get; set; }
}
```

Aunque no lo indicas en tu pregunta, mi respuesta asume que utilizas Newtonsoft para deserializar. He tomado como base el método `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject...` para llegar a esta conclusión.

Comment: En primer lugar, agradecerte mucho tu respuesta y sobre todo tu explicación @pablo-gutiérrez. Aunque haya funcionado perfectamente, no acabo de entender porque la propiedad "lista" no le es útil y ha de llamarse "visitors".

Comment: Debe existir una correspondencia entre las propiedades del objeto reconstruido y los campos incluidos en el JSON. Si no existe de manera implícita (por los nombres de propiedades) o explícita (mediante atributos, como te muestra Pablo Gutiérrez), entonces no se sabrá qué hacer con esos valores del JSON y la implementación general es ignorar ese campo.