# Como convertir un Json que tiene dos objetos

Tags: c#, json, api

quisiera preguntarles como convertir un json que estoy descargando de una api con la particularidad de que dicho json tiene un primer objeto y luego viene una lista de otros objetos, a continuación, les muestro cual es la estructura de dicho archivo:

```
{
    "Paging": {
        "PageNumber": 1,
        "PageSize": 10,
        "MoreData": false
    },
    "Data": [
        {
            "Code": "01",
            "Name": "TRANSPORTE PROPIO",
            "IVACategory": "Responsable Inscripto",
            "Cuit": null,
            "SurchargePercentage": 10.0000000,
            "Address": "Av.Santa Fe 1284 ",
            "PostalCode": "1010",
            "City": "Capital Federal",
            "ProvinceCode": "01",
            "PhoneNumbers": "4816-2589",
            "Email": "info@ejemplo.com.ar",
            "WebPage": "www.ejemplo.com.ar",
            "Comments": null
        },
        {
            "Code": "02",
            "Name": "TRANSPORTES LA ESTRELLA",
            "IVACategory": "Responsable Inscripto",
            "Cuit": null,
            "SurchargePercentage": 0.0000000,
            "Address": "Salta 348 ",
            "PostalCode": "1010",
            "City": "Capital Federal",
            "ProvinceCode": "01",
            "PhoneNumbers": "4816-2695",
            "Email": "transporteestrella@ejemplo.com.ar",
            "WebPage": "www.transporteestrella.com.ar",
            "Comments": null
        },
        {
            "Code": "03",
            "Name": "TRANSPORTE SILVANA",
            "IVACategory": "",
            "Cuit": null,
            "SurchargePercentage": null,
            "Address": "",
            "PostalCode": "",
            "City": "",
            "ProvinceCode": "01",
            "PhoneNumbers": "",
            "Email": "",
            "WebPage": "",
            "Comments": null
        }
    ],
    "PagingError": null
}
```

Como pueden ver, tengo un primer objeto llamado Paging y luego Data, que es la lista de objetos, en este caso objetos transporte.

Estoy procesando esto mediante C#, he logrado establecer la comunicación con el API sin inconvenientes pero me tira un error cuando intento desserializar.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando:

```
private void btSubirDtos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = "https://tiendas.axoft.com/api/Aperture/Transport?pageSize=500&pageNumber=1";
    WebRequest peticion = WebRequest.Create(url);
    peticion.Method = "get";
    peticion.ContentType = "application/json;charset-UTF-8";
    peticion.Headers.Add("accesstoken:" + "5092e0d3-ed60-4fb2-bb54-b26f323cfe09_12516");

    WebResponse _respu = peticion.GetResponse();

    using (var oSR = new StreamReader(_respu.GetResponseStream()))
    {

        string _json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oSR.ReadToEnd().Trim(), Formatting.Indented);

        List<Api.ApiTransportes> lstTranspo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Api.ApiTransportes>>(_json);

    }
}
```

Muchas gracias, espero me puedan ayudar. Saludos

Estas serían las clases que estoy usando, tal como me sugieren abajo

```
 class ApiTransportes
    {
        public Paginacion _paginacion { get; set; }
        public List<TransportesData> _transportes { get; set; }
    }


 class Paginacion
    {
        public string PageNumber { get; set; }
        public string PageSize { get; set; }
        public string MoreData { get; set; }
    }


class TransportesData
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string IVACategory { get; set; }
        public string Cuit { get; set; }
        public double SurchargePercentage { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string ProvinceCode { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string WebPage { get; set; }
        public object Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

Ok, acabo de corregir la propiedad que faltaba pero sigue tirando error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Solo tienes que crear tu modelo tal cual como es ese json, con un objeto "Paging" y otro "Data" que seria una lista de objetos que seria otra clase

Comment: Seria bueno que edites tu pregunta y pongas la estructura de tu clase Api.TRansportes tambien

Comment: He dado un vistazo rápido a tu inconveniente veo que te hace falta la propiedad PagingError en tu clase ApiTransportes... Verifica eso.

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/452696/182188) te servirá como guía para resolver el error cuya causa está en el nombre de las propiedades (en tu caso de la clase `ApiTransportes`)

Comment: Ya he resuelto el problema, no tenía que intentar serializar la respuesta de la api, simplemente se debe procesar el txt que está devolviendo y listo. Igualmente muchas gracias por los aportes realizados.